# Conditional WHERE clause in KDB?

Tags: kdb

**Full Query:**

```
{[tier;company;ccy; startdate; enddate] select Deal_Time, Deal_Date from DEALONLINE_REMOVED where ?[company = `All; 1b; COMPANY = company], ?[tier = `All;; TIER = tier], Deal_Date within(startdate;enddate), Status = `Completed, ?[ccy = `All;1b;CCY_Pair = ccy]}
```

**Particular Query:**

```
where ?[company = `All; 1b; COMPANY = company], ?[tier = `All; 1b; TIER = tier],
```

What this query is trying to do is to get the viewstate of a dropdown.

If there dropdown selection is "All", that where clause i.e. `company` or `tier` is invalidated, and **all** companies or tiers are shown.

I am unsure if the query above is correct as I am getting weird charts when displaying them on KDB dashboard.

Comment: Have you thought of using a parse tree? You could then have if statements that would check the value of company and tier. If they are equal to ALL you can set add them to your parse tree and build out your functional query. See the link for some detail https://code.kx.com/v2/basics/funsql/#select
or use the parse command to help build your query 
Ex. 

`parse"select c1,c2 from t where c1=`IBM,c2>23"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would recommend is to restructure your function to make use of the where clause using [functional qSQL](https://code.kx.com/v2/basics/funsql/).

In your case, you need to be able to filter based on certain input, if its "All" then don't filter else filter on that input. Something like this could work.

```
/Define sample table
DEALONLINE_REMOVED:([]Deal_time:10#.z.p;Deal_Date:10?.z.d;Company:10?`MSFT`AAPL`GOOGL;TIER:10?`1`2`3)

/New function which joins to where clause 
{[company;tier]
  wc:();
  if[not company=`All;wc:wc,enlist (=;`Company;enlist company)];
  if[not tier=`All;wc:wc,enlist (=;`TIER;enlist tier)];
  ?[DEALONLINE_REMOVED;wc;0b;()]
}[`MSFT;`2]
```

If you replace the input with `All you will see that everything is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The full functional select for your query would be as follows:

```
whcl:{[tier;company;ccy;startdate;enddate]
 wc:(enlist (within;`Deal_Date;(enlist;startdate;enddate))),(enlist (=;`Status;enlist `Completed)),
 $[tier=`All;();enlist (=;`TIER;enlist tier)],
 $[company=`All;()enlist (=;`COMPANY;enlist company)],
 $[ccy=`All;();enlist (=;`CCY_Pair;enlist ccy)];
 ?[`DEALONLINE_REMOVED;wc;0b;`Deal_Time`Deal_Date!`Deal_Time`Deal_Date]
}
```

The first part specifies your date range and `` status = `Completed `` in the where clause

```
wc:(enlist (within;`Deal_Date;(enlist;startdate;enddate))),(enlist (=;`Status;enlist `Completed)),
```

Next each of these conditionals checks for `All for the TIER, COMPANY and CCY_Pair column filtering. It then joins these on to the where clause when a specific TIER, COMPANY or CCY_Pair are specified. (otherwise an empty list is joined on):

```
 $[tier=`All;();enlist (=;`TIER;enlist tier)],
 $[company=`All;();enlist (=;`COMPANY;enlist company)],
 $[ccy=`All;();enlist (=;`CCY_Pair;enlist ccy)];
```

Finally, the select statement is called in its functional form as follows, with wc as the where clause:

`` ?[`DEALONLINE_REMOVED;wc;0b;`Deal_Time`Deal_Date!`Deal_Time`Deal_Date] ``

Comment: Hi Matt, just a few things on your code structure. I wouldn't recommend explicitly defining a variable like "x" given that this a reserved name - [implicit parameters.](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#617-implicit-parameters). Also, you don't need to use $ if-else in this case, and when you're using $ by default it will always output something so no need for the ":"

Comment: x,y,z are not reserved names (`.Q.res`), nor part of the reserved single letter namespace. For simple functions the use of implicit x,y,z is acceptable, similarly, the habit of working explicitly is also fine. It's important to strike a balance between terse and verbose code in order to maximise readability.